# How can I set the order of duplicated widgets in tkinter, python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

I use image(image1) for background and made Entry with create_window method.
And I want to make image(image2) cover the entry with create_image method.
But the Entry widget is revealed everytime.(Entry - image2 - imgae1)
How can I change the order of these like image2- Entry - image1.
My code is like below.

```
        self.img_main = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Bart\My library\Python\Grinding\GUI\capture\image1.png")
        self.canvas_main = Canvas(self, width=1366, height=768, bd=0)
        self.canvas_main.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.canvas_main.create_image(0,0, image=self.img_main, anchor=NW)

        self.entry = Entry(self, width=12, justify="center", bg="#A5C1DE")
        self.canvas_main.create_window(72, 287, height=32, anchor=NW, window=self.entry)

        self.cbb_pro_sel_img_1 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Bart\My library\Python\Grinding\GUI\capture\image2.png")
        self.cbb_pro_sel = self.canvas_main.create_image(36, 75, anchor=NW, image=self.cbb_pro_sel_img_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot raise an image object on a canvas above an embedded widget. From the canvas documentation:

> The items in a canvas are ordered for purposes of display, with the first item in the display list being displayed first, followed by the next item in the list, and so on. Items later in the display list obscure those that are earlier in the display list and are sometimes referred to as being “on top” of earlier items. When a new item is created it is placed at the end of the display list, on top of everything else. Widget commands may be used to re-arrange the order of the display list. **Window items are an exception to the above rules. The underlying window systems require them always to be drawn on top of other items.**

Instead, you can create a label that contains the image and then use `create_window` to put the label over the entry. Since it is a widget, it can appear above the entry widget.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! :) If I use Label, the transparent part of the image is not transparent anymore. I'll think about it more.